# Online grading says my output values are not correct but I don't see why?

Tags: java

I am doing some homework for my java programming class, but this code is giving me trouble. The online program that grades it says there is a problem with my output, but I really don't see why. Can anyone help?

## The assignment:

Write a class  named  Car that has the following fields:

- yearModel: The yearModel field is an int  that holds the car's year model.
- make: The make field is a String  object  that holds the make of the car.
- speed: The speed field is an int  that holds the car's current speed.

In addition, the class  should have the following methods :

- Constructor : The constructor  should accept the car's year model and make as arguments .
  These values  should be assigned  to the object 's yearModel and make fields. The 
  constructor  should also assign  0 to the speed field.
- Accessor: The appropriate accessor methods  should be implemented to access the values 
  stored  in the object 's yearModel, make, and speed fields.
- accelerate: The accelerate method  should add 5 to the speed field when it is called.
- brake: The brake method  should subtract 5 from the speed field each time it is called.

Demonstrate the class  in a program  that contains a Car object , and then calls the 
accelerate method  five times. After each call to the accelerate method , get the current
speed of the car and print it on a separate line. Then, call the brake method  five times,
each time printing the current speed of the car on a separate line.

## My code:

```
public class Car {
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int model, String m) {
        yearModel = model;
        make = m;
        speed = 0;
    }

    public int getYearModel() {
        return yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return speed;
    }

    public int accelerate() {
        speed += 5;
        return speed;
    }

    public int brake(int b) {
        b -= 5;
        return b;
    }
}

class CarDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car c = new Car(1992, "Mustang");
        int s = 0;
        s = c.getSpeed();

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println("The " + c.getYearModel() + " " + c.getMake() + "is going: " + s);

            s = c.accelerate();

            System.out.println("Now the " + c.getYearModel() + " " + c.getMake() + "is going: " + s);
        }
    }
}
```

---

## Edit:

Based on the suggestions below, I have edited my code to the following; however, the system still says that my output is incorrect.

```
public class Car{
    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;
    public Car(int y, String m){
        yearModel = y;
        make = m;
        speed = 0;
    }
    public int getYearModel(){
        return yearModel;
    }
    public String getMake(){
        return make;
    }
    public int getSpeed(){
        return speed;
    }
    public void accelerate(){
        speed += 5;
    }
    public void brake(){
        speed -= 5;
    }
}
class CarDemo{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Car theCar = new Car(2010, "Porsch");

        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
            theCar.accelerate();
            System.out.println(theCar.getSpeed());
        }

        for(int count = 0; count < 5; count++){
            theCar.brake();
            System.out.println(theCar.getSpeed());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Show us your output. Additionally, do you have any example expected input/output?

Comment: Read the last two lines of the assignment. You're just not doing what it asks you to do.

Comment: @BilltheLizard is correct, you are printing more results than you need.  It wants to know the current speed, not what the speed was and now is

Comment: Off topic, but as a Detroiter I must point out that "Mustang" is a model; "Ford" would be the make.

Answer (score 1):

for brake you need to do speed -= 5, not b -= 5. Also I do not think the brake method needs an input argument.

In addition you accelerate 5 times but never brake

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the specification.**

The spec says:

> - accelerate: The accelerate method should add 5 to the speed field when it is called.
> - brake: The brake method should subtract 5 from the speed field each time it is called.

These 2 methods **have no return type** and **take no arguments**.

So, they should be:

```
public void accelerate() {
    speed += 5;
}

// brake should not take an argument
public void brake() {
    // this should be speed, not b
    speed -= 5;
}
```

Additionally, your demo should follow the spec (in comments):

```
class CarDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Demonstrate the class in a program that contains a Car object 
        Car c = new Car(1992, "Mustang");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //and then calls the accelerate method five times. 
            c.accelerate();

            //After each call to the accelerate method, get the current speed of the car and print it on a separate line. 
            System.out.println(c.getSpeed());
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            //Then, call the brake method five times,
            c.brake();

            //each time printing the current speed of the car on a separate line.
            System.out.println(c.getSpeed());
        }
    }
}
```

When working off of a well-written, explicit specification as has been provided for your assignment, it can be very helpful to do what I've done above--include the spec as comments and fill in the code around them.

Comment: Well, now you have to make a very hard decision. Either remove the unnecessary method argument `b`, or add a value to `c.brake()`, since it needs an argument :D.

Comment: @Tom d'oh! missed that too.

Comment: ok so now I have made my program a bit simpler (for my own reading sake), but it is still saying that my output is incorrect. My new code can be found above in my original post. It says the output should be: 5 10 15 20 25 20 15 10 5 0

Comment: @mador96 when you run your new code, what does it output?

Comment: To be honest, I am unsure of how to run this program in my command prompt since it has two classes

Comment: @mador96 I believe you can run it the same as any other file and it will find main. If that doesn't work, pull your `CarDemo` class out to its own file for testing purposes.

Comment: @LukeWillis First of all, thank you for your help so far. So, I took your advice and split up my classes, and ran the CarDemo. The ouput in my console is 5
10
15
20
25
20
15
10
5
0  ..... this is the exact answer the assignment is calling for, but it still says my output is incorrect...

Comment: @mador96 No problem. Based on the output, it sounds like we've fixed your program. :) You should accept an answer at this point. If it's still not working, I'd ask your professor or a classmate if there is any weird stuff you need to do in order to get the system to work. For example, I've used some online submission systems which would not accept an answer if it didn't end its output with an additional new line (ie. `System.out.println()`) at the very end.

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is the `brake` method. The requirements state that it should subtract 5 from the current speed. So, you should make it like your `accelerate` method, but subtracting 5 instead of adding. It shouldn't take in a parameter.

Also, I don't know if this would cause an issue, but your `accelerate` and `brake` methods shouldn't  return the speed, according to the requirements. Change their return types to `void`, and remove the return statements.

Lastly, You test `main` doesn't do exactly what the requirements say to do. Read it carefully to see what it should do, and do EXACTLY what it says.

Answer (score 0):

You're printing `The " + c.getYearModel() + " " + c.getMake() + "is going: " + s` 5 times. You should put that outside the loop so it's printed once only.

IMHO I don't think you need to be returning the speed from the accelerate() function either. I'd suggest making that a `void` function and using the `getSpeed()` method instead of assigning to an intermediate variable.

Comment: The first part is not what the spec requires.

Comment: True, but I was answering while in the middle of something else earlier :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am currently taking the Prog Fund I & II class. If you are using Pearson, then this *should* help. I had the answer correct the first time. You just have to format it correctly in the proper order as so.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Car
{
    private int yearModel;      // Holds the car's year model
    private String make;        // Holds the make of the car
    private int speed;          // Holds the car's current speed

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Creates car object
    Car vehicle = new Car(2018, "Barbie Mobile");

    // Creates object for user input
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    // Holds the speed of the car
    int speed = 0;

    // Calls accelerate 5 times
    vehicle.accelerate();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.accelerate();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.accelerate();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.accelerate();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.accelerate();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    // Calls break 5 times
    vehicle.brake();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.brake();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.brake();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.brake();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

    vehicle.brake();
    speed = vehicle.getSpeed();
    System.out.println(speed);

}



public Car(int year, String maker)
{
    // Assigns values to car's year model and make
    yearModel = year;
    make = maker;

    // Assigns 0 to the speed field
    speed = 0;
}

/* @return gets year model */
public int getYearModel() 
{
    return yearModel;
}


/* @return The speed */
public int getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

/* @return Gets the making of car */
public String getMake()
{
    return make;
}

/* Adds 5 to speed when called */
public void accelerate()
{
    speed += 5;
}

/* Subtracts 5 from speed when called */
public void brake()
{
    speed -= 5;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I am taking the same class right now, using Pearson Revel. If anyone else comes across this problem, this should help.. **Spoiler alert, I will be posting the answer to the problem below**

Pearson Revel is such a pain in the butt, they do a horrible job describing how they want the programs structured and output displayed, and if anything is off by even one space or something similar, you lose all points. That being said, the problem demonstrates the calling of the program under "Sample Run" as `java Car`. So it sounds like the main program that creates a Car object and calls all of it's methods is within the same class (test it out in a text editor, you'll see that if you create a seperate class under the Car class and call Car.java from the command line, it will throw an error; stating the class Car does not have a main. So therefore, it's safe to say you need to create the main method inside of the Car class (wish they would just say that, right?).

### Here is my graded & passing answer.

```
public class Car {

    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int year, String make) {
        this.yearModel = year;
        this.make = make;
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    public void brake() {
        this.speed -= 5;
    }

    public void accelerate() {
        this.speed += 5;
    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return this.speed;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return this.make;
    }

    public int getYearModel() {
        return this.yearModel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car myCar = new Car(2019, "Tacoma");

        for (int i=0;i < 5;i++) {
            myCar.accelerate();
            System.out.println(myCar.getSpeed());
        }

        for (int i=0;i < 5;i++) {
            myCar.brake();
            System.out.println(myCar.getSpeed());
        }
    }
}
```

### And here is Revel's suggested answer after completion

```
public class Car {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Car batmobile = new Car(1965, "Bat Mobile");

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            batmobile.accelerate();
            System.out.println(batmobile.getSpeed());
        }

        for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
            batmobile.brake();
            System.out.println(batmobile.getSpeed());
        }
    }

    private int yearModel;
    private String make;
    private int speed;

    public Car(int yearModel, String make){
        this.yearModel = yearModel;
        this.make = make;
        this.speed = 0;
    }

    public int getYearModel(){
        return this.yearModel;
    }

    public String getMake(){
        return this.make;
    }

    public int getSpeed(){
        return this.speed;
    }

    public void accelerate(){
        this.speed += 5;
    }

    public void brake(){
        this.speed -= 5;
    }
}
```